# Barcode scanner for a web application using phonegap and html5 and jquery

Tags: jquery, html, cordova, phonegap-build

I am trying to develop a web application targeting different platforms like IOS, Android, windows. For this im using html5, CSS3 and jquery with phonegap. I have searched for a code which can used for phonegap, but when i try on android its not working. can you please help me.

Comment: https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeDemo this i found but not working  when i tried apk using phonegap

Answer (score 1):

Well... Since you aren't saying what specifically isn't working... I'll just run through the general steps...

Step 1.... Use this https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/BarcodeScanner

Step 2.... Follow the instructions right on the readme.

Step 3.... If you want to actually test the scanner to make sure it works. You can create a button to to start scanning...

In the index.html put somewhere: `<button id="scan" style="padding: 10px;">Scan!</button>`

Then in the javascript on index.html (or anywhere really where it's included on index.html) put:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    app.initialize();
    function init(){
        $("#scan").click(function(){
            console.log("I am now scanning");
            window.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan( function(result){
                alert("We got a barcode\n" +
                "Result: " + result.text + "\n" + 
                "Format: " + result.format + "\n" + 
                "Cancelled: " + result.cancelled);
            }, function(error){
                alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
            });
        });
    }
</script>
```

Additionally note that I am using jquery when doing the `$("#scan").click(...`

Following the steps on the readme I was able to get it to work... So if it still doesn't work... clarify it